Angular 8 to Angular 9 migration differences between budgets
I finished a migration from Angular 8 to Angular 9 with the same packages and same code with no major modifications between the codes. I am encountering a budgets error when doing ng build --prod. Could it be that Angular 9 uses memory in a different way in terms of compilation than Angular 8 ?
WARNING in budgets: Exceeded maximum budget for initial-es2015. Budget 2 MB was not met by 13.8 MB with a total of 15.8 MB.
WARNING in budgets: Exceeded maximum budget for initial-es5. Budget 2 MB was not met by 15.6 MB with a total of 17.6 MB.
ERROR in budgets: Exceeded maximum budget for initial-es2015. Budget 5 MB was not met by 10.8 MB with a total of 15.8 MB.
ERROR in budgets: Exceeded maximum budget for initial-es5. Budget 5 MB was not met by 12.6 MB with a total of 17.6 MB.
"budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]

if I modify it to
{
"type": "initial",
"maximumWarning": "12mb",
"maximumError": "20mb"
} ng build prod works correctly.

My guess for the size difference is the presence of both Ivy and View Engine in Angular 9. Either way those bundles are waaaaay too big: have you thought about using lazy loading?

But are there any compiler differences in terms of memory between Angular 9 and Angular 8 ? Because I have the same packages updated to the compatible version. Would lazy loading solve the budget problem? Thanks in Advance!

I solved the issue setting optimization to true in Angular.json
